# Sending plain text e-mails using SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a plain text e-mail from a C# function; however, the resulting mail comes through with HTML tags.  I've reduced this down to the following console app:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    SendGridMessage msg = new SendGridMessage()
    {
        From = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress("noreply@test.com"),
        Subject = "test",
        PlainTextContent = "Hello"
    };
    msg.AddTo(new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress("my@address.com", "test recipient"));            

    SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient("mykey");
    Response response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

It sends the e-mail fine, but doing a view source on the e-mail shows it to be HTML formatted:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>

<img src="https:// ... />
</body></html>
```

I've tried various combinations, including setting the HtmlContent to plain text (which results in a very different e-mail, but still not plain text), and a syntax such as:

```
var emailContent = new Content
{
    Type = "text/plain",
    Value = emailMessage
};
message.Content.Add(emailContent);
```

I know that there is no intermediary reformatting the message, as I can send a plain text e-mail to myself from outlook.

I'm using SendGrid 9.9.0, but I've tried 9.8.0 in case it's something that has recently changed.

Am I missing something here, or am I expecting SendGrid to be able to do something that it isn't capable of?

Comment: What is the value of the `Contents` property of the `SendGridMessage`, right before you send? My guess is that it contains HTML, and you simply need to remove that entry from the list. Just a guess, based on the [source code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs). I've not used SendGrid myself.

Comment: it is also very important question how do you do the operation `view source` of the message?

Comment: Contents is null.  Like I said above, if I populate contents manually, then it's whatever I set it to (e.g. "text/plain", "msg"), but it makes no difference to the resulting e-mail

Comment: @astaykov Right click on the message in outlook and select view source

Comment: Have you tried setting the mime type, i.e.`msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, "hello");` (obviously without setting the `PlainTextContent` when constructing the object)

Comment: That didn't work.  I had previously tried setting "text/plain"; but setting MimeType.Text just results in exactly the same Contents

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from the [SendGrid online docs:](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Format_Content/html_formatting_issues.html)

> First, login to your SendGrid account, click on “Settings”, then “Mail
>   Settings”, and drop down the Plain Content setting, and then place a
>   check mark in the Don’t Convert Plaintext to HTML option. Be sure to
>   save this setting.

The standard seems to be that e-mails are sent with both HTML and plain text, so a version of plain text is automatically converted to HTML as well.

Comment: Thanks - I did see that, but I took it as a global override (of course, when you see the way it's worded it sort of makes sense)

Comment: Looks like Sendgrid has retired this setting in January. Not sure what the alternative is: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/retired-mail-settings/